# ansible roles does not run the main playbook

Tags: ansible

site.yml

```
  name: setup basic packages
  hosts: all
  user: root

  roles:test
```

./test/tasks/main.yml

```
  name: this is a loose task
  shell: echo 'this is a loose task'
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

site.yml

```
---
- name: setup basic packages
  hosts: all
  user: root

  roles:test
```

roles/test/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: this is a loose task
  shell: echo 'this is a loose task'
```